# Docker phusion/baseimage install oracle_db

Tags: java, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper, dockerfile

Can someone help me install oracle_db client on my existing docker image. I tried so hard to get around a fix for this issue. Looks impossible to install oracle_db with phusion/baseimage.

My dockerfile is this:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

MAINTAINER bugsbunny

RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"

RUN apt-get -y update 

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q python-software-properties software-properties-common

ENV JAVA_VER 8

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

RUN echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886 && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-set-default && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk${JAVA_VER}-installer

RUN update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle

RUN echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN apt-get install nano

RUN apt-get install -y ksh

RUN echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update 

RUN cd /home/ && wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/333072908/libaio1_0.3.110-4_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libaio1_0.3.110-4_amd64.deb

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD mtf-release /home/mtf-release

ADD instantclient_12_2 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2

RUN sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf" && ldconfig

RUN  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN  mkdir -p /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/network/admin

RUN export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$PATH


#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python"]
```

As you can see, I need java:8 version and oracle_db client, sqlplus to make my docker work. Is there any proper docker image which has java + oracledb or anyway to merge two docker images into one so that I have both installed working fine.? Thank you.

Can someone help me with using two FROMs and what all images i need?

Comment: have you take a look at this http://dbaontap.com/2017/07/17/oracle-instant-client-docker-oracle-db/ and for the smaller image you can use alpine base https://github.com/cosmomill/docker-alpine-oracle-xe

Comment: I agree they let me run oracle client. I mentioned i needed oracle java 8 on my docker. So, I have written this dockerfile. Can you tell me how to use those images on to my dockerfile. Sorry if this question is too newb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a Docker image that container both oracle client and java.

Oracle provides a Docker image for the instant client and the source code for the Docker file can be found [here](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile).

For Java there are many Docker images available such as [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/).

You can merge the two images using Docker multi-stage builds. Before that make sure to login into docker store, go to [oracle instantclient image](https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-instant-client), and accept the license and pull the image `docker pull store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1`

```
FROM store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 as oracle

FROM openjdk:8-jdk 
COPY --from=oracle /usr/lib/oracle /usr/lib/oracle
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin
```

Once you build the above dockerfile you will have a docker image containing java and oracle instantclient.

Comment: I can't add any repositories or do an apt-get install. Error shows /bin/sh -c command `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y package name' returned a non-zero code: 100`. Also when i run, it shows $ORACLE_HOME is not set.